Docker permission error when using host user
I have a dockerfile installing a FastApi web service, using a custom user for accessing the /app folder, which is the folder that contains the web server.
I'm able to build the container, but I want to run it using the host user, since I want to preserve the permissions I have in some of the folder on the host(this is mandatory).
The problem is that the web service has a Logger class that persist a file.log on the container, but I'm getting a permission error(13) since I am assuming the host user does not have permissions to persist on the container within /home/developer/.logs
Dockerfile
RUN useradd -m developer
RUN chown -R developer:developer /app
RUN chmod 777 /home/developer && setfacl -d -m u::rwx,g::rwx,o::rwx /home/developer 
USER developer
WORKDIR /app

Docker Run
docker run -it -u $(id -u):$(id -g) --name container_name image -v mounting_some_volumes
Error
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.logs'

I gave 777 permissions to the folder containing the logs and even I tried to mount that folder as a volume.
Any idea on how I can run the container using host user without getting errors?
Thanks,

Permission denied: '/.logs' That is a file (or maybe a directory) named .logs in the root directory.  Is that what you intended?  Maybe you meant ./logs instead?

For logs specifically, usually the best practice is to log to stdout, at which point docker logs can retrieve them.  Popular log collectors can scrape these logs, or you can configure Docker logging to push the logs somewhere directly.

Perhaps the logs path is being set with a variable, e.g. $HOME/.logs, where $HOME is not defined by default in a container. A [mcve] is needed to further assist.
